# Function to delete node gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

This is my code:

```
def dn(self,x):
    curr = self.head
    while curr is not None:
        if(curr==x):
            break
        curr=curr.next
        prev= curr
    temp = curr.next
    prev.next= temp
    return self.head
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

What is my mistake?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- When the `while` loop exits without finding `x`, then `curr` will be `None` and an error occurs when evaluating `curr.next`. So you should foresee the case where `x` is not found and not alter anything to the linked list in that case.
- When `x` happens to be the head node, then `prev` will never have received a value, and so `prev.next =` will raise an error.
- The code does not foresee that the head of the list might need to change.

Not a problem, but:

- Since the instance has a `head` attribute, there should be no need for the function to *return* the head node. If the caller needs this information, they can read the `head` attribute.
- Give meaningful names. `dn` is cryptic. Name your method `delete` or `deletenode`.

Corrected code:

```py
def deletenode(self, x):
    prev = None  # Initialise
    curr = self.head
    while curr:
        if curr == x:
            break
        curr = curr.next
        prev = curr
    else:  # curr is None
        return self.head # List does not have the value
    temp = curr.next
    if prev:  # It is not the head node that is to be removed
        prev.next = temp
    else:  # The head node is to be removed
        self.head = temp
    # Don't return anything
```